# Why GASP doesn't work when I run it from IDLE?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle, gasp

I made this script:

```
from gasp import *
begin_graphics()

Circle((200, 200), 60)
Line((100, 400), (580, 200))
Box((400, 350), 120, 100)

update_when('key_pressed')
end_graphics()
```

When I start it from terminal, it works perfectly. When I run it from IDLE, it doesn't work, I get no answer (shell prompt (>>>) disappears but nothing happens).

Comment: What do you mean by "run it from shell" as opposed to "start it from terminal"? To most people, those are generally the same case—you're running a shell (bash, cmd.exe, whatever) in a terminal (Terminal.app, kterm, cmd.exe itself, whatever). If you mean something different, please explain it.

Comment: @abarnert I mean that window that opens when you enter idle in terminal (menu bar of that window says Python 2.7.6 Shell. My mistake, I should wrote IDLE (corrected).

Comment: OK, no problem, it just helps to be clear. And in this case, I'll bet it's directly relevant to the problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't run GUI apps in the embedded Python interpreter in IDLE, unless the library you're using is designed to integrate with IDLE. Or, worse, it may work on one machine and not on another. I'll explain why below, but first just take that on faith.

As far as I can tell, `gasp`'s documentation doesn't address this, but similar libraries either warn you that they may not work in IDLE ([`easygui`](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial/), early versions of [`graphics`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py), etc.) or come with special instructions for how to use them in IDLE (e.g., later versions of `graphics`).

Now, maybe `gasp` should be designed to integrate with IDLE, given that it's specifically designed for novices, and many of those novices will be using the IDE that comes built in with Python. Or maybe not. But, even if that should be true, that's something for `gasp` to deal with. File a bug or feature request, but you'll need some way to keep working until someone gets around to writing the code.

The simplest solution here is to use a different IDE, one that runs its interactive Python interpreter in a completely separate process, exactly the same as you get when running it yourself in the terminal. There are lots of good options out there that are at least free (-as-in-beer) for non-commercial use (PyCharm, Komodo, Eclipse PyDev, emacs with your favorite collection of packages, etc.). Although Stack Overflow is not a good place for advice on picking the best one for you (if googling isn't sufficient, try asking on a mailing list or forum), almost any of them will work.

Another option: instead of using an interpreter built into an IDE, you might want to to consider running an enhanced interpreter environment (like ipython-gtk or emacs with a smaller set of packages) alongside your IDE. Of course they'll no longer be tightly integrated (the "I" in "IDE"), but in my experience, even working in an environment where the whole team uses PyCharm or PyDev, I still end up doing most of my interactive testing in ipython; you may find you prefer that as well. Or you may not, but give it a try and see.

---

So, why is there a problem in the first place?

First, if you don't understand what an "event loop" or "runloop" or "mainloop" is, please read either [Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) or [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) or some other introduction to the idea.

Normally, when you run the interactive Python interpreter (e.g., by typing `python` at the bash or C: prompt in your terminal), it runs in its own process. So, it can start up a runloop and never return (until you quit), and the terminal won't get in your way.

But when you run the interactive Python interpreter inside IDLE, it's actually running in the same process as IDLE, which has its own runloop. If you start up a runloop and never return, IDLE's runloop doesn't get to run. That means it doesn't get to respond to events from the OS, like "refresh your window" or "prepare for a new window to open", so from the user's (your) point of view, IDLE and your app are both just frozen.

One way to get around this is in your code is to spawn another thread for your runloop, instead of taking over the main thread. (This doesn't work with all GUI libraries, but it works with some. This is how `graphics` solved the problem.) Another way is to spawn a whole new child process to run your GUI. (This works with all GUI libraries, but it's a lot more work—now you have to deal with inter-process communication. One of the novice-friendly `matplotlib` wrappers does this.) Finally, you can integrate your runloop with IDLE's Tkinter runloop by having one drive the other. (Not all GUI libraries can be driven this way, but Tkinter's can, and IDLE can be monkeypatched to work this way; `graphics` used to do this.) But none of these are even remotely simple. And they're probably things that `gasp` itself should be doing, not your code.